# Getting sport statistics for mobile app development

Tags: web-services, rss, mobile-application

I have to create a mobile-application mobile application that provides actual (or real time) information about ice hockey events.  I need information about schedules, statistics and so on. Is there a reliable source (RSS, web service...) to obtain these information? How do other similar applications work? What do they use as data source for automatic regular download? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ESPN API](http://developer.espn.com/branding) should give you all the information you need, I tried that for different sport before and it worked as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it looks good, but I also need statistics of KHL. At ESPN they have only NHL and some other leagues, but no KHL.